# Optimizing a filtering loop that checks a couple of conditions

Tags: java, optimization

I am working on a project that executes a series of calculations on a large dataset.

The calculation process is rather slow at this point so that's why I took my first shot at using a profiler to determine which methods can be optimized.

A significant amount of total time is spent in one small method so my aim is to optimize this method. I'm not sure how I can do it and would like some hints.

```
private List<EventEntry> getImpactedEntries(LocalDate referenceDate) {
    return eventDomain.getEventEntries().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getDate().isAfter(referenceDate) && ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(referenceDate, entry.getDate()) <= 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This small filtering is executed thousands of times during the process. It loops a list of entries (~250 items) and does two date-based checks on it.

My guess at this point is that to optimize this I have to somehow prepare the data beforehand using some way of indexing.

One idea I have is sorting the entries beforehand and then looping through only partially in this method.

I'd start with finding the entry that's after the referenceDate, this would give me the starting index. Then I'd continue looping until I find an entry that's more than 2 months away (the second loop) and quit the looping.

However I doubt that this will actually speed up the algorithm that much. Does anyone have a better idea or suggestion?

Comment: How is the result of this method used?

Comment: Assuming `eventDomain.getEventEntries()` is a list, I would sort it, and then (binary?) search to find the first and last entries matching entries in the list - then, use `List.subList(first, last)` to return a view of those entries. That's going to be much more efficient than copying the list for each date.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing that and it's a lot faster now!